# Reset Password Form Page not found

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have built a custom password reset in Django, however, after putting the information in `'PasswordResetForm'` I get a 404 page not found error.

This is my code for reset_password:

```
def reset_password(request,username):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordResetForm(data=request.POST, user=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, form.user)
            #added this to redirect user to custom url
            username = request.user.username
            return redirect(reverse('main:home', kwargs={'username': username})) 
            #return redirect(reverse('main:home'))
        else:
            return redirect(reverse('main:reset_password'))
    else:
        form = PasswordResetForm(user=request.user)
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'reset_password.html', args)
```

My urls at myapp/urls.py

```
urlpatterns=[
    path('signup/',views.signup,name='signup'),
    path('login',views.user_login,name='user_login'),
    path('',views.main_page,name='main_page'),
    path('<str:username>', views.home, name='home'),
    #replace home/edit with below
    path('<str:username>/edit', views.edit_profile, name='edit_profile'),
    path('<str:username>/password-reset', views.reset_password, name='reset_password'),
]
```

and my form for password reset:

```
class PasswordResetForm(PasswordChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('old_password','new_password1','new_password2')
```

What seems to be the problem here?  I do not know why I am getting this error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/main/test3-b/login.html?next=/main/test3-b/password-reset
```

This is my AbstractUser model in models.py (I do not have any other code in my models.py

```
class Profile(AbstractUser):
    bio = models.TextField() 
    university = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your urls.py is not using the same path as the URL you are accessing.  The URL example you have given is http://127.0.0.1:8000/main/test3-b/login.html but your password reset url is something like http://127.0.0.1:8000/example-user/password-reset where `example-user` is the username that you are trying to match inside your path.

Out of interest do you have the URL structure include a username? This is normally not wanted as you would be using request.user to access the current user.  You also have the risk a users username could break your patterns as you are using str rather than slug which is safer in URL patterns as otherwise id a user was created with the username of "example/edit" then they would never be able to get to your homepage as it would match the edit_profile entry instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks! I realized my mistake I fixed it. I changed my url structure for security reasons as well now everything seems to be working fine

Answer (score 0):

I saw that by the form rendered in HTML it does not reset the admin user password, however the others works. In my case, I just extended the user class and inserted the email field.